# Response in HTTP Connection (GET) is always 401(Unauthorized) in eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse

```
public static String GET(String url)
{
    String response = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    URL URL = null;
    try {

        URL = new URL(url);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) URL.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", LoginActivity.tokenJson);
        urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        if(urlConnection.getResponseCode()== HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        }
        else
        {
            InputStream stream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
            response = readStream(stream);
        }

        }   
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    urlConnection.disconnect();
    return response;
}
```

I am getting good result in sending my request in POST method but in GET, the response is always unauthorized. what should I do? 
My team mate is getting good response in IOS. thanks

Comment: can we see the POST method?

Comment: Wrong `Authorization` token?

Comment: @Henry token was produced after the login method in POST. Sample token - mavshack_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhY2NvdW50SWQiOiI1N2FiYjVkOC0xOWNlLTQ5MjItYjE1YS00MmNmZDFiY2ZmYjEiLCJzZXNzaW9uSWQiOiI4NTE2ZTZkNC1jY2E2LTQ4MGUtOWVhZi1hNTM0NGZhNzI4N2IiLCJpYXQiOjE0NzcwMzI3MDUsImV4cCI6MTQ3OTYyNDcwNX0.4-IsIUcOt8TYC6b2mRGfODr41XKHw_hzABvb3Q4yI-I; Domain=.mavshack.com; Expires=Sun, 20 Nov 2016 06:51:45 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira pardon me. I'm not behind a proxy. We were given URLs and we are using POSTMAN to verify the URLs. I can get the result using postman.

Comment: what is *exactly* the value of `LoginActivity.tokenJson`?

Comment: @nandsito my comment in henry at the top. mavshack_token up to secure. the back end developer said to put it in authorization header

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I've change the authorization to cookie and it worked. backend problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Authorization` header looks like this:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l
```

The header value is `Basic`, then a whitespace, then a RFC2045-MIME Base64 value that doesn't wrap lines. [(reference)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

The access token seems to be the value between the first `=` and the first `;`, excluding these boundaries. It doesn't seem to follow RFC2045, but nonetheless try using it as the Base64 value. If it doesn't work, you'll have to concatenate a username, a colon `:`, a password, then convert the concatenation to Base64 and use it as the Authorization payload.